# How to enable BlueTooth when TX/RX already being used

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, serial

We have the TX/RX Gpio already being used on the Raspberry Pi 3B+ . I believe the onboard Bluetooth uses the same ? How can I get bluetooth working when our TX/RX is already being used.

Right now I've tried a lot of things.. bluetoothctl returns most often "no control device found" ..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have fiddled with it, Bluetooth uses `/dev/ttyAMA0` and the serial port `/dev/ttyS0`. These are different devices.

You should use `/dev/serial0` for serial rather than the physical port.

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way of **alternatively speak** with **one device** and **then the other**.

I think **managing the UART** in the way that you configure it on the the go to speak with the bluetooh then the PINs is possible.
**Some sort of script** to make the switch **in the OS** may be needed…

But **you will not be able to speak to both devices at the same time**, thus i believe one of the Raspberry's UART (the mini) is difficult to use (speed varying, etc).